# Run or debug a test with specific configuration in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: reactjs, testing, intellij-idea, jestjs

I have a project with Clojure in server-side and React in client-side.

The project has two run\build configurations, one REPL based for the server-side and a Jest based for the client-side.

Both the context menu and the green 'play' icon to run a specific test show the same option to run the test with REPL even-though the file is a Javascript file and I expect it to run using the Jest configuration.

I've tried to play around with the workspace.xml file to set the Jest configuration as the default one (I saw that configurations have a 'default' attribute in the xml) but that only caused weird issues with invalid configuration options in the configurations dropdown.

I need to have the ability to run a specific test by clicking the green 'play' button instead of setting-up a specific configuration for each test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic currently used by **JavaScript support** plugin for detecting what test runner is available for a given test file is based on dependencies declarations in `package.json` nearest to this file, so, if you have `jest` or `jest-cli` listed among your client dependencies, you should be able to run Jest tests from gutter. But note that this behavior can be overridden by other plugins that register their actions for tests running

Comment: I think that the Cursive plugin causes this issue.
After removing the Cursive plugin I see that I can run tests using the Jest configuration.
Thanks for the input.